# How to say “You’re fucking cute.” and “You’re so fucking cute.”

Tags: traduction

I want to say “You’re fucking cute.” and You’re so fucking cute.” in french.

I learnt from this [article](https://frenchtogether.com/putain/) that « putain de » precedes a noun and is roughly equivalent to the word **“fucking”** when it’s being used as an adjective. So, "Ma putain de voiture est si belle" means my “My fucking car is so beautiful.”

But the word “cute” is an adjective not a noun.  So how do I say the sentence **“You’re fucking cute”** and **“You’re so fucking cute.”**?

Ideally, I’m looking for a construction in which the whole of France can understand not just a construction only a specific region of France can understand. :)

Also, I would like to say that the function of **fucking** here is just to inform the listener that he/she is cute to a very high degree. This isn’t offensive. Whether this statement is offensive, as with all statements, depends on who’s saying it, who’s it being said to as well as the place and time it is being said. I was watching a movie in which the wife said this to her husband who was feeling self-conscious. I wanted to know if a similar thing exists in French.

Comment: I'd say *Tu es putain de belle/jolie*. *Putain de* works quite the same as in english, as you said, and you cas use almost the same as in english for every use you can find ;)

Comment: A piece of advice: never ever say "You’re fucking cute" to anyone. If you have a good friend, you could tell him "That girl is fucking cute", but to say that to a woman that you find attractive is a full assurance that she will wish only one thing: never see you again. En français, c'est à peu près la même chose. Il est absolument impossible de dire en face à une femme, "Vous êtes vraiment bandante", au moins dans un stade préliminaire d'une relation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you said, before a noun:

> My fucking car is so beautiful!
>
> Ma putain de voiture est tellement belle !

Before an adjective:

> My car is so fucking beautiful!
>
> Ma voiture est putain de belle !

As you can see I removed the word *tellement* because it's more natural this way, but you could say *est tellement putain de belle* or *est putain de tellement belle*.

Now I'd say it's not very common to use this formulation before an adjective, at least not as common as using it before a noun. I would rather say *Ma voiture est tellement belle, putain !*.

It's possible before an adverb too, and similarly to before an adjective, I'd say it's not the most natural way:

> My car is moving so fucking slowly!
>
> Ma voiture avance (tellement) putain de lentement !

I'd rather say *Ma voiture avance tellement lentement, putain !*

Comment: I like the way that you avoided the (not very common) use of "putain de" before an adjective by simply ending the sentences with "putain" (I also like that all of your examples were about a car, thus avoiding the [potentially?/blatantly!] offensive use of "putain" in sentences describing a woman!). Back to "putain" at the end of the sentences, do you think "Putain [que]" could also begin the sentences and still have the same meaning/impact as your putting it at the end? (eg: "Putain [que] ma voiture est tellement belle!) Thanks!

Comment: @PapaPoule To me, putting it at the beginning or the end doesn't change the meaning. In your last example I wouldn't use "tellement" if I use "que". Similar to English "How beautiful it is!", I think "How so beautiful it is!" sounds wrong.

Comment: [Part 1] @Destal This is very long overdue but thank you so much for your help!!!  Please can you correct me if I’m wrong but I’m guessing (1) “You’re fxcking cute.” = « Tu es putain de mignon(ne). » and (2) “You are so fxcking cute.” = « Tu es (tellement) putain de mignon(ne). » ??? Also, I would like to say that the function of *fxcking* here is just to inform the listener that he/she is cute to a very high degree. This isn’t offensive.

Comment: [Part 2] Whether this statement is offensive, as with all statements, depends on who’s saying it, who’s it being said to as well as the place and time it is being said. I was actually watching a movie in which the wife said this to her husband who was feeling self-conscious. I wanted to know if a similar thing exists in French. Lol, I think I should have mentioned all of this in my question. Sorry! 

Comment: Your sentences are correct but I wouldn't use "tellement" if I use "putain de", even if I would use "so fucking" in English. And using it before an adjective is not very natural, at least for me, so the way I would say that is: "Putain, tu es tellement mignonne" (Fuck, you're so cute). About the offensive part, "putain" is a noun that means "whore" but I think it's really stronger in French than in English, it's like the worst thing you can say to a woman. Even when using kinky words during sex or being offensive to friends as a joke, this one sounds too strong.

Comment: Again this is very late and I’m really sorry for that but thank ever ever ever ever ever so much for helping me to figure out how to convey the same meaning in French @Destal and happy holidays !!! 

Answer (score 5):

I think that using a "suitable" emphasizing/emphatic adverb constructed with the usual "ment" suffix would sound smoother than "putain de" and better avoid any possible implication that the recipient of your complement has "whorish" qualities.

["Sacrément"](https://cnrtl.fr/definition/sacr%C3%A9ment) or one of the synonyms (especially, but not necessarily the vulgar one) for it mentioned in the linked *TLFi/CNRTL* entry might work:

> SACRÉMENT, adv.,
>   ...
>   DÉR.
>   **Sacrément**, adv.,pop. Tout à fait, extrêmement. Synon. bigrement (fam.), bougrement (fam.), diablement (fam.), **foutrement** (vulg.), vachement (pop.).

"T'es sacrément/foutrement/vachement/(**>>>**) belle/beau/mignonne/mignon, toi"

(**>>>** You could also consider ["fichtrement"](https://cnrtl.fr/definition/fichtrement), in my opinion.)

Comment: Ou le joli *gavé* qui doit venir de quelque part dans le Sud. *T'es gavé belle*.

Answer (score 1):

**I** You can use that most successful of intensifiers even with an adjective;  there is a clear tendency though: the adjective shouldn't be of that sort that shows a quality and should be of the disapproving kind. There is a range of moods associated with such elocutionary behaviour, from grudgingly friendly to downright mean. It should be known that whatever the attitude, using this term makes for language  of a very inferior quality, not at all advised to speakers that want to preserve their French a clean language; all of this that follows in the examples is utterly coarse.

- Mais t'es putain de têtu, comment je vais te faire comprendre ? (*recollections*)
- Elle est si putain de [bête (*rare*)/con] qu'elle fout du fromage dans son thé. (*recollections*)

However, the rule concerning the disapproving character of the adjective is not a hard and fast one;

- C'est si putain de bon qu'ils se mettent à quatre pattes pour le boire dans la mare du tonneau renversé. (*quasi recollections*)
- Elle est si putain de grande que ses genoux se voient au-dessus du tableau de bord. (*quasi recollections*)

I wouldn't know about "cute" (mignonne); it seems I never heard such a combination of ideas, which amounts to the crudest of terms being allied to one expressing the most delicate and divine perception in order to connote a high degree of the quality.

**II** This usage is rather rare in print, where for the quasi totality of the uses of "putain de" the complement is a noun. Personally, I think that this  "pioneering" English usage itself (fucking cute) goes one degree further in the way of making for an unnatural  and contrived language.

Answer (score 1):

In Southern France, at least in Marseille's area, you might hear:

> *Tu es putain qué jolie/mignonne/belle !*

*Qué* being a remnant of Occitan.

Otherwise, this would work all over France:

> *Putain, que tu es mignonne !*

Answer (score 1):

*Putain* est certainement [utile](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/fucking/582403) dans bien des contextes en français métropolitain, entre autres, et l'adverbe *tellement* peut en effet exprimer le haut degré.

En français du Québec/Canada le l'adjectif [*maudit*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/maudit#Adjectif) peut servir à accentuer et on a l'adverbe [*mauditement*](https://www.cordial.fr/dictionnaire/definition/mauditement.php), mais on est loin du compte en ce qui a trait au niveau de vulgarité. On peut possiblement recourir au sacre directement, en locution adverbiale avec *en* (*en... [crisse](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sacre_qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9cois#Crisse), tabarnac, sacrament*, etc. : beaucoup sont identifiés comme *vulgaires* par [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/en_mautadit#Synonymes)) ; l'adverbe *crissement* est usuel.

> Cette personne est belle *en maudit/crisse*<sup>1</sup>.
>  Cette personne est
>   *mauditement/crissement* belle.

<sub><sup>1</sup> Dans un cadre où la syntaxe est très relâchée, il peut y avoir confusion possible entre le haut degré/locution adverbiale et une réduction d'une locution verbale ou d'un emploi différent, « quand elle est en [crisse](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%AAtre_en_crisse)/[maudit](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/maudit#Nom_commun) » (en colère).</sub>

Answer (score 0):

`cute` can be use everywhere beautiful is used, with one condition : this must be an animal, a human, ... so something that live. Also, with *cute/beautiful*, we would prefer to translate it as *tellement* instead of *putain*, which is really familiar (and can be insulting).

A car didn't live (only mechanic and electronic), so you can't use `cute` in that case. But for a cat, you can use both.

In french, that's not a problem, both *belle* and *jolie* (both refered to `beautiful`) can be used for tools, plants or animals. But *cute* would more refered to `mignon`.

Examples : about a draw :

- in english, I would say *My draw is fucking beautiful, a masterpiece !*
- in french, we could say *Mon dessin est tellement joli / beau, un chef d'oeuvre*

about a baby :

- in english : *That baby is so fucking cute, he grabbed my hand.*
- in french : *Ce bébé est tellement mignon, il a attrapé ma main.*

NB : you could use *mignon* in the 1st example, but the sentence would totally change about what is described (we would about what is drawn, and not the draw in global - a cat drawn for example)

Comment: *Fucking* definitely not translates to *tellement*... *Putain* is vulgar as *fucking* is in English.